# Trying to create an offset using javascript and a fixed headbar

Tags: javascript, css, header, fixed

I was trying to calculate the size of a fixed header with an ID "headbar" so that I could use the value to create an offset for the main page. The javascript code seems to be working- at least the console.log seems to be okay. However, the css doesn't update and I don't know why. Can someone help me out?

Here's the javascript.

```
headresize();
window.addEventListener('resize', headresize);

function headresize(){
  var h = document.getElementById("headbar").clientHeight;
  document.getElementById("logo").style.paddingtop = h+"px";
  var c = document.getElementById("logo").style.paddingtop;
  console.log(h+"px");
  console.log(c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since javascript is case sensitive, you should use **paddingTop** instead of paddingtop:

```
document.getElementById("logo").style.paddingTop = h+"px";
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I was getting so frustrated!